# How to break page in crystal report after name change?

Tags: crystal-reports

I created one report that displays all the items purchased by Hotels. Now what i want is : If hotel name is change then page must be break and if hotel name is same then in same page. and also want grand total for particular hotel.

can anyone help me for this ?

Answer (score 0):

In Report -> Group Expert you need to have a group set up based on Hotel Name.

Then in Section Expert select the Hotel Name group and click on the Paging tab on the right hand side and tick "New Page After"

Comment: I did it already, but problem is: it also break the page when hotel name is same..

Comment: 1. How many groups do you have?  Which number group is Hotel name? How many purchased items print before you get a new page?

Comment: I have 2 groups : 1st for Purchase id  and 2nd I created for hotel name.

Comment: What i want is: same hotel purchase items are group together with their total. then break the page and then another hotel and it's total

Comment: Make Hotel group 1